# Tools to view logical address

Tags: c, linux, unix, memory, nm

I am a new in linux system programming. My question is:

- What are the address type when we run the command "nm a.out" - Is it the logical 
  addresses?
- Is there  linux tools to view all types of addresses - for example is there a tool to 
  view logical address - linear address - virtual address?
- What is the type of the address &x in this code:

```
    int x;
    printf("%p", &x);
```

Answer (score 0):

In user space you are dealing with linear addressing where linear address == logical address == virtual address.  In other words, there is only a single address space.  If you have two pointers with the same value, they are referring to the same object in memory.

Answer (score -1):

In x86_64 CPU, there is 3 type of address:

- Logical address (0x08:0x12345678): this kind of address have segment:offset format. The segment part control permission (kernel, user), mode (32bit or 64bit), base, limit. The offset part is the offset into that segment. Logical -> Linear address translation is: linear address = segment base + offset. In 64bit mode, all segment have base=0 and limit=0xffffffff, which is ignored by the cpu (except fs and gs segment), this make all logical address = linear address
- Linear address (virtual address): this is the address modern operating system use since it is mandatory for 64 bit longmode
- Physical address: the address that goes out to system bus and then to RAM

About your question:

- What are the address type when we run the command "nm a.out" - Is it the logical addresses?

  - No, it's linear (virtual) address
- What is the type of the address &x in this code: int x; printf("%p", &x);

  - Linear (virtual) address
- Is there linux tools to view all types of addresses - for example is there a tool to view logical address - linear address - virtual address?

  - No, linear (virtual) address -> physical address translation is controlled by a struct called paging struct, each process have one of them. The struct is inside kernel space and controlled by kernel so user space program can't access it. But you can see all your program linear (virtual) address when you're debugging your program